# How do I count the specific candles from a file?

Tags: matlab

I am completely new to Matlab programming language. I have written a program that gets the data from YahooFinance and plot's a candlestick chart, next I would like to count the total number of specific candlesticks included in a file. However I am getting an error `Attempt to reference field of non-strcture array`. I am aiming to count any two candles which looks like this: [LINK](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3nqvkoljvxzx63g/example.png): I cannot post a picture here as I require 10rep so I've uploaded on my dropebox

This is what I have completed so far:

```
clear;
close all;
str = urlread('http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AMZN&a=0&b=1&c=2008&d=0&e=31&n=2014&g=d&ignore=.csv');
i = 0;

[dates,o,h,l,c] = dataread('string',str,'%s%f%f%f%f%*f%*f','delimiter',',','headerlines',1);
dates = datenum(dates);
previousDate = dates-1; %start from previous date
curDate = previousDate+1;

if (previousDate (previousDate.o < curDate.o) && (previousDate.c > curDate.c) )
   i = i+1;
end

save('output.txt','i','-ASCII');
```

If you open the above link you will see .csv file streaming into your browser, the file will contain date, open, close etc… any data underneath is associated with headings for example:

```
    Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
    2014-07-18,354.40,359.68,352.08,358.66,3407400,358.66
    2014-07-17,353.44,356.96,351.38,352.45,3636000,352.45
    2014-07-16,355.62,359.32,353.00,355.90,3503600,355.90
```

from this what I want is the program to read all the data in that file and count the number of  records that have this out:

check the previous date, if previous date open price is less than next date opening price AND previous date closing data is more than next date then record this into a file. Now lets see this in action: This is my historical data from the .csv file (c/p this to get this data `http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AMZN&a=0&b=1&c=2008&d=0&e=31&n=2014&g=d&ignore=.csv`):

```
    Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
    2014-07-18,354.40,359.68,352.08,358.66,3407400,358.66
    2014-07-17,353.44,356.96,351.38,352.45,3636000,352.45
    2014-07-16,355.62,359.32,353.00,355.90,3503600,355.90
```

First I tell my program to take first two line:

```
    Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
    2014-07-18,354.40,359.68,352.08,358.66,3407400,358.66 <-- 1st line - this is a second date 
    2014-07-17,353.44,356.96,351.38,352.45,3636000,352.45 <-- 2nd line - this is previous date
```

Now check is the previous date (2014-07-17) open price 353.44 < 354.40 && close price 352.45 > 358.66 (previous date) then record this into file (1) now move into second line which is:

Now do the same thing, if the condition matches then record this in file (2). keep doing this till until the program reach to the end of file.

```
     2014-07-17,353.44,356.96,351.38,352.45,3636000,352.45
     2014-07-16,355.62,359.32,353.00,355.90,3503600,355.90
```

Let me know if this is still confusing!

Comment: What did you intend to do with `previousDate.o`? `previousDate` is a matrix, not a struct

Comment: @LuisMendo I am try to use previous date and say if the opening and closing price is whatever to current date (means if program detects any two of the candlesticks shown in the above picture) then +1 to i. my aim is to count total number of candles shown in a picture from the file

Comment: Your code can probably be simplified, but you should explain what are `dates`,  `o`, `l`, `c` and what result you expect; ideally with a small example

Comment: @LuisMendo ohhkk- if you copy and past http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AMZN&a=0&b=1&c=2008&d=0&e=31&n=2014&g=d&ign‌​ore=.csv you will get historical data of Google if you read at the top there is a heading e.g. date, open, high, low etc.. I have updated my question now it should be more clear